# Can sklearn.tree.export_graphviz be reused for one's own data structures?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graph-visualization

I've been looking for a good way in Python to draw an abstract syntax tree to PNG. A combination of networkx and matplotlib seems to be able to do the job well enough to get by.

But I just noticed that https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html does much better! This applies when using sklearn to generate a random forest; it is a function specific to the resulting decision trees.

Is there a way to supply an arbitrary tree to the above function, or to some version of the code behind it, to obtain the high-quality rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple [graphviz](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html). There is [examples](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) how to draw your own data structures.